# Android change view with GCM push notification

Tags: android, layout, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When app is notified, i need an some action in app like change view, set text from GCMIntentService. For example, when push notified while app is running, the icon will be red.

I tried these codes but nothing changed.

In GCMIntentService.java

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_activity, null);

ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_tab_home_btn);
img.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Also

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() { 
           //some codes
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly confusing- i'm assuming what you're saying is that you want to add functionality so that when a notification is clicked by the user, you can be navigated to a specific view in your application.

Your best option is probably to let the GCMIntentService.java class handle the intent, and have the intent be carried out by some other class. Since your going to change the view based on that notifications intent, I would recommend putting it in whatever your main activity class is.

If i'm not mistaken, this kind of activity is really part of a pending intent- the active intent being to actually notify the user, but eventually, to load your application in some unique way.

So, in your GCMIntentServices class, wherever you're handling the notification (or this could be in your Receiver class, it's really up to you)

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DummyActivity.class);
```

Then, you'll want to establish a Pending intent to be issued after passing the first intent to DummyActivity.class

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Now, It is important that in whichever class you have that extends Activity, you establish some function that can get this pending intent and do what you want (in this case, load some View)

In DummyActivity.class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

handleNewIntent(getIntent());
  }
```

Then, the method for handleNewIntent:

```
public void handleNewIntent(Intent intent) {

  Bundle payload = intent.getExtras(); 
  //You could add some string to uniquely identify each message and what you want it to   
  //do

  String wheretogo = intent.getStringExtra("something");
  if (wheretogo == "blah") {
    //LayoutInflater
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheretogo, null); 
  } else {
    //otherwise load something different
  }
```

Hope this helps. To add something to your message pending intent, in your receiver class or in the intent, wherever you're unloading the payload, just do something like

```
    pendingIntent.putExtra("something","blah");
```